# How to get CMMotionActivity in total steps

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, core-motion, apple-m7

I was wondering if this possible. I able to grab total steps. which is not very helpful. I thought, If I can get total motion activity, for example, walking or running activities distance or steps. So I can calculate calories based on this.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out CMStepCounter.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMStepCounter_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013504

and CMStepQueryHandler, CMStepUpdateHandler
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMStepCounter_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CMStepQueryHandler